# Java JButton - making simple menu

Tags: java, swing, button, frame, actionlistener

Hi take a look on this code:
package arkanoid;

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Arkanoid extends JFrame 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6253310598075887445L;
static JFrame frame;


static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
        //frame = new JFrame("Arkanoid");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.add(new Gra());
      }
    }   
    static class Action2 implements ActionListener {        
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
          frame.dispose();
          System.exit(0);
      }
} 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //new Arkanoid();
      frame = new JFrame("Arkanoid");
      frame.setSize(500,400);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setTitle("Arkanoid BETA");
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      frame.add(panel);

      JButton button = new JButton("Nowa Gra");
      panel.add(button);
      button.addActionListener (new Action1());

      JButton button2 = new JButton("Wyjscie");
      panel.add(button2);
      button2.addActionListener (new Action2());
}
}
```

This code almost works, I want to make a button2 a quit button working like X button in top right frame's icons and button1 need to open a Gra() in the same window. When im doing it like this it isnt work fine:/ i need to click 2 times on button1 to go to Gra() and what is more KeyListeners in Gra() arent working :( 
Im new in buttons, frames and panels in java so please help with this code. Correct it please.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of fundamental problems with your code, the least of which is why your `button1` requires 2 clicks.

However, for your problem you should try rearranging the order of your `button1` listener, so that your `Component` is added to the frame first, before setting it to be visible. An example that should work:

```
static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {   
        frame.add(new Gra());
        frame.revalidate();
     }
}
```

Note you have already set the size, location etc of `frame` in `main`, so there is no need to set them again every time the button is clicked.

I stress that there are more important problems with your code than this issue. You should take a look at Java's Modifier Types (`static` does not seem applicable here), as well as object-oriented concepts such as inheritance (you define your `Arkanoid` class to extend `JFrame`, yet have a `JFrame` object as a class variable).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make a button2 a quit button working like X button in top right frame's

You can use the `ExitAction` class found in [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

For other examples of how to use buttons read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). This is the place to start for all you Swing related questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code. I've refactored it a little. With below code & @ricky116 answer I think you should get all of them.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Arkanoid extends JFrame 
{
    public Arkanoid() {
        super("Arkanoid");
        setSize(500,400);
        setTitle("Arkanoid BETA");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panel);

        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Nowa Gra") {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
              panel.removeAll();
              panel.add(new Gra());
              panel.revalidate();
              panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Wyjscie") {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
                Arkanoid.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              Arkanoid frame = new Arkanoid();
              frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```